# Network or Transport Layer Fuzzing

Tags: networking, transport, fuzzer, fuzzing

How do I go about executing a fuzzing strategy to stress a network stack, specifically at the third and fourth layers (network and transport)? I've looked at frameworks to generate fuzzers, like SPIKE, but it seems to me that they are mostly focused on the application layer and above? Is there any well known techniques out there to fuzz well-known protocols in these layers, say, TCP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Look at [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/).  It allows you to fuzz at the network and transport layers.  The `fuzz` function will fuzz anything you didn't explicitly specify in the IP or TCP layers (you can apply it separately to each).  This gives you a range of abilities from just randomly generating ip addresses and port pairs to making and sending nonsense packets.

You may also want to look at [Fragroute](http://monkey.org/~dugsong/fragroute/).  This will twist TCP/IP into using all sorts of evasions techniques, but could potentially unveil otherwise hidden bugs/vulnerabilities in your network stack.

Furthermore, if your organization doesn't object, you could set up a [Tor](http://www.torproject.org/) exit node and capture traffic from it.  I've found it useful for testing correct TCP connection state tracking. Though your end of the connections is well-known and unchanging, there's a huge variety of servers as well as fun network congestion issues.  It's basically an endless source of traffic.  Be sure to check with your higher ups as your org may object to being a potential source of malicious traffic (even though there is a strong precedent of non-liability).  I've gotten around that issue by running it/capturing at home, then bringing in the pcaps.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fuzz the IP, UDP, or TCP route your packets from your high level services via loopback to a process that reads them, fuzzes them, and forwards them.  You need a driver that lets you talk to raw sockets and you need to read/learn what the applicable RFCs say for those protocols.

There is an easy way to do this.  Just as Justdelegard recommends, Scapy is probably the best thing to use, in general.

Take a look at [Releasing ICMPv4/IP fuzzer prototype](http://g-laurent.blogspot.com/2009/11/releasing-icmpv4ip-fuzzer-prototype.html) by Laurent Gaffié.  His Python code, which incidentally he has reposted in [more readable](http://pastebin.com/f5c536013) fashion at pastebin.com, imports from scapy and uses some methods he defines to do a couple of types of fuzzing.  IP and ICMP packets are handled in his sample code.  So, this sounds exactly like what you are seeking.

Right now, there seems to be a lot of companies using [Tcl/Expect to do custom automated testing](http://www.job-search-engine.com/keyword/test-automation-tcl) of networks.  SIP, H.323, layer 2 & 3 protocols, etc.

So if Scapy does not meet your needs, you might be able to make or find something written in Tcl using Expect to do the job.  Or, you may wish to do some things in Python, using Scapy - and other things in Tcl, using Expect.

Tcl has long been used for network test and management applications.  There was a book on how to use Tcl to do SNMP-based network management way back in the 1990's.

Syntax of Tcl is decidedly odd but the libraries are very powerful.  It comes with a framework-like ability to define behavior of custom network behavior atop sockets, similar to what you can do with the standard libraries for the Python programming language.

Unlike Python and other scripting languages, there is an extremely powerful tool for Tcl programs named Expect (see [expect man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html)).

Expect has a handy capability.  It can auto generate a Tcl test script.  The generated script makes calls to Expect functions. When doing this recording, it functions as a passive man-in-the-middle, recording both sides of the conversation.  Kind of the way that you record Macros while you  do some editing in MS Word or in Emacs.

Then afterward, you can edit the automatically-generated Expect script to fine tune it, make it behave differently, or creation multiple variations of it.  It is very handy for creating regression tests.  You should be able to use this to kickstart writing higher layer protocol tests, should you need some.  Beats starting from scratch.

I think you can use Tcl/Expect to test standard TCP applications (FTP, HTTP, SMTP, etc.) that use string based commands. It works well for testing character based applications like TELNET that read input from stdin and generate output to stdout too.